# Determination is made of whether log4j can encrypt either log messages or files

Tags: java

Currently, I was assigned atask of rsearching the idea that log4j files can be encrypted and then in turn can also be decrypted.  I am kind of at a loss and trying to find good source code which may help?  I have found items about the RollingFileAppender.  Here is some other information to assist with responses:

The intent is to allow us to go in and modify an existing log4j configuration such that all text written to the log is encrypted.   Once the file is encrypted, we need some viewer

Comment: You need the *entire* log file encrypted?!

Comment: What's this good for (some context may help)?

Comment: Yep according to this task the output file needs to be encrypted.

Comment: There is a decent amount of information here
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629755/creating-an-encrypted-log-file

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass FileAppender with your own implementation, so if you write a class that encrypts the data being written that would do the trick. You would have to write something to view it yourself.