# Chunking AES symmetric encryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric, symmetric-key

**Use case 1 (working baseline):**

*Use case one is straightforward and is implemented / working.*

1. In Java, Write a stream to disk in a single fell swoop.
2. Wrap output stream with symmetric cipher so that contents on disk are encrypted.
3. Later, read from disk. Wrap input stream with same symmetric cipher
   in a single fell swoop so that contents retrieved from input stream
   are plaintext and match original.

**Use case 2 (no suitable solution determined):**

1. In Java, Write a stream to disk.
2. Allow for subsequent bytes ("chunks") to be appended to file.
3. Wrap output stream with symmetric cipher so that contents on disk are encrypted.
4. Use same cipher so that all chunks are encrypted in the same manner.
5. Later, read from disk. Wrap input stream with same symmetric cipher
   in a single fell swoop so that contents retrieved from input stream
   are plaintext and match original.

**Problem statement:**

Encrypting and decrypting "abc" does not yield the same result as encrypting and decrypting "a", "b", and "c" separately, and therefore the "chunked" file described in use case 2 will no be successfully decrypted.

```
// e.g.
decrypt(encrypt("abc")) != decrypt(encrypt("a") + encrypt("b") + encrypt("c"))
```

**The Actual Question:**

... so the question is, how might one configure a Java cipher stream that can encrypt one chunk at a time, (a) without having prior knowledge of encrypted chunks, and (b) be decipherable using a **single** input stream cipher wrapper (without requiring knowledge of indexes where file was appended)...

Comment: Joking aside... given your current problem statement, there is no solution that meets your stated requirements. Are you definitely constrained to using an encryption algorithm where `encrypt("abc") != encrypt("a") + encrypt("b") + encrypt("c")`? When you say `(without requiring knowledge of indexes where file was appended)`, does that mean you're prohibited from using any means of recording or detecting a special series of bytes to indicate chunk beginning or chunk length?

Comment: @gnicker, "does that mean you're prohibited from using any means of recording or detecting a special series of bytes to indicate chunk beginning or chunk length?" - Ideally I wouldn't have to save meta data saying "we appended this file at byte 0, 1052, 10002331, and 232323231.  So treat each one of these sections ( [0,1052], [10002331], etc ) as separately encrypted subsections.  I would rather build an input stream for the entire file, ie [0 ,len(file)] and wrap it with a single decryption stream that is unaware of the "breakpoints."

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283637/how-to-append-to-aes-encrypted-file

Comment: That can't work generally for AES. If you can restrict your breakpoints to the multiple of the blocksize then it is possible.

Comment: @ArtjomB. - Alternative to managing breakpoints, why not use PKCS5Padding?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in this case you can't have your cake and eat it too.

You must either

1. write some length bytes at the start of each chunk, or
2. use an encryption algorithm where `decrypt(encrypt("abc")) == decrypt(encrypt("a") + encrypt("b") + encrypt("c"))` (aka trivial, and not recommended)

Number 1 is definitely a better choice, and is easier than you might think. Details below.

Number 2, you could use something like a [Vigenere cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), which would allow you to decrypt the whole file in one fell swoop, but would be a compromise in terms of encryption strength.

**Details on number 1**

The way you would do this is by reserving, for instance, four bytes (a 32-bit integer) at the beginning of each chunk. This integer represents the length of the chunk. To decrypt you would therefore:

1. Read the first four bytes and convert to integer `n`.
2. Read the next `n` bytes and decrypt.
3. Read the next four bytes and convert to integer `n`.
4. Read the next `n` bytes, decrypt and append to the first decrypted chunk.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until end of file is reached.

And obviously this makes the chunk encryption easy because all you have to do is first write how many encrypted bytes you're about to append.

Comment: Vigenere won't work because it's character-based, and very weak.

Comment: Option two needs a correction.  I've edited the original post to read "decrypt(encrypt("abc")) == decrypt(encrypt("a") + encrypt("b") + encrypt("c"))" instead of "encrypt("abc") == encrypt("a") + encrypt("b") + encrypt("c")"

Comment: I see option one working, but it would require a proprietary decipher stream.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution close enough to my particular problem (stealing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283637/how-to-append-to-aes-encrypted-file)), albeit slightly different from the problem statement (not a single stream).

```
public static void appendAES(File file, byte[] data, byte[] key) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    RandomAccessFile rfile = new RandomAccessFile(file,"rw");
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    byte[] lastBlock = null;
    if (rfile.length() % 16L != 0L) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file length (not a multiple of block size)");
    } else if (rfile.length() == 16) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file length (need 2 blocks for iv and data)");
    } else if (rfile.length() == 0L) { 
        // new file: start by appending an IV
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
        rfile.write(iv);
        // we have our iv, and there's no prior data to reencrypt
    } else { 
        // file length is at least 2 blocks
        rfile.seek(rfile.length()-32); // second to last block
        rfile.read(iv); // get iv
        byte[] lastBlockEnc = new byte[16]; 
            // last block
            // it's padded, so we'll decrypt it and 
            // save it for the beginning of our data
        rfile.read(lastBlockEnc);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        lastBlock = cipher.doFinal(lastBlockEnc);
        rfile.seek(rfile.length()-16); 
            // position ourselves to overwrite the last block
    } 
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] out;
    if (lastBlock != null) { // lastBlock is null if we're starting a new file
        out = cipher.update(lastBlock);
        if (out != null) rfile.write(out);
    }
    out = cipher.doFinal(data);
    rfile.write(out);
    rfile.close();
}

public static void decryptAES(File file, OutputStream out, byte[] key) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    // nothing special here, decrypt as usual
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    if (fin.read(iv) < 16) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file length (needs a full block for iv)");
    };
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] buff = new byte[1<<13]; //8kiB
    while (true) {
        int count = fin.read(buff);
        if (count == buff.length) {
            out.write(cipher.update(buff));
        } else {
            out.write(cipher.doFinal(buff,0,count));
            break;
        }
    }
    fin.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // prep the new encrypted output file reference
    File encryptedFileSpec = File.createTempFile("chunked_aes_encrypted.", ".test");

    // prep the new decrypted output file reference
    File decryptedFileSpec = File.createTempFile("chunked_aes_decrypted.", ".test");

    // generate a key spec 
    byte[] keySpec = new byte[]{0,12,2,8,4,5,6,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

    // for debug/test purposes only, keep track of what's written 
    StringBuilder plainTextLog = new StringBuilder();

    // perform chunked output
    for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++) {

        // generate random text of variable length
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            text.append(UUID.randomUUID().toString()); // append random string
        }

        // record it for later comparison
        plainTextLog.append(text.toString());

        // write it out
        byte[] b = text.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        appendAES(encryptedFileSpec, b, keySpec);
    }

    System.out.println("Encrypted " + encryptedFileSpec.getAbsolutePath());

    // decrypt
    decryptAES(encryptedFileSpec, new FileOutputStream(decryptedFileSpec), keySpec);
    System.out.println("Decrypted " + decryptedFileSpec.getAbsolutePath());

    // compare expected output to actual
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] expectedDigest = md.digest(plainTextLog.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

    byte[] expectedBytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(expectedDigest);
    System.out.println("Expected decrypted content: " + new String(expectedBytesEncoded));

    byte[] actualBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(decryptedFileSpec.toURI()));
    byte[] actualDigest = md.digest(actualBytes);
    byte[] actualBytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(actualDigest);
    System.out.println("> Actual decrypted content: " + new String(actualBytesEncoded));


}
```